# BeautifulSoup not finding tr id

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've run this web scraping exercise using the requests and BeautifulSoup module in python 2.7.12. My problem is that I can't seem to get the soup object to return a specific tr based on the id, as well as a few other html elements with id that I've picked at random including the ones in the below print statements. Any idea why that's not working? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

head= {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type': 'text/html',}

r = requests.get('http://www.iii.co.uk/investment/detail?code=cotn:LSE:SEE&display=discussion', headers=head)

r_text = r.text
soup = bs(r_text, "html.parser")

print soup.find("tr",id="disc1-12056888")
print soup.find('table', id='discussion-list')
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use `BS` instead of another library? for simpler things I like to use `PyQuery` and it use DOM selectors to extract information.

Comment: can you share r_text ?

Comment: @RafaelAguilar nope. just wanted to scrape the site for comments. would you suggest PyQuery for that?

Comment: @Shijo no, I tried by stack recognizes it as spam

Comment: when you do a `print soup` do you see the `tr` you are trying to get in the soup?

Comment: @AndrewF Yes, I've made an example snippet so you can try it out.

Comment: @AndrewF what output are you getting with the above code? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I'm getting a 'None' on the print return statement

Comment: @AndrewF interesting, works for me as is. Did it work for you before?

Comment: @alecxe  hey, that's really weird. could you please share all your code with me to try it out in my IDE. And no it didn't work on those print statements at all.

Comment: @AndrewF I've just executed the code as is. Have you tried to change `html.parser` to, say, `html5lib` or `lxml` (they need to be installed)?

Comment: @alecxe hey, sorry for the bother but the strangest thing happened next. I reloaded the page and it worked but it's not giving me all the elements again. To give you a more concrete example, in this one here: `print soup.find('table', id='discussion-list') `. I get the output ` </thead>
<input name="code" type="hidden" value="cotn:SEE.L"/>
<input name="it" type="hidden" value="le"/>
<input name="display" type="hidden" value="discussion"/>
</table>` at the end of the print. But in the source code there's a tbody before the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `html.parser` is unstable is python2, use `lxml` or `html5lib`

```
soup = bs(r_text, "lxml")
```

This quote is from [Document](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#problems-after-installation):

> If you can, I recommend you install and use lxml for speed. If you’re
>   using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version of Python
>   3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install lxml or
>   html5lib–**Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in older
>   versions.**

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH !!! I was struggling to find the reason for this for sooo long. Just for my future reference, is there a specific place to find out if there are bugs in package and version combo I'm using?

Comment: @AndrewF the reason why I know this bug is I answered a lot this question in stack overflow. If you can, I recommend you install and use lxml for speed. If you’re using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version of Python 3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install lxml or html5lib–Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in older versions.

Answer (score 1):

@AndrewF:

I'd suggest you to use `PyQuery` for simpler tasks as extract comments, here is a snippet to show the simplicity of it:

```
import requests
import pyquery

head= {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36',
'Content-Type': 'text/html',}

r = requests.get('http://www.iii.co.uk/investment/detail?code=cotn:LSE:SEE&display=discussion', headers=head)

r_text = r.text
pq = pyquery.PyQuery(r_text)

for a in pq('tr.comment div'):
    if a.text.strip():
        print(a.text.strip())
```

Comment: thanks! this did prove to be an easier way to go about it.